TP4056 charge discharge for a NiMH prius battery?
I want to make a capacity tester for a 6 cell module for prius batteries. They have 6000mAh new and anywhere from 2500-5000 mAH used. I was wondering if theTP4056 would work for a NiMH battery and if there was something like that that charges with more than 1 amp

TP4056 is not for NiMH battery.

@Justme is there an equivalent for  TP4056 or would I have to make one?

There's no way the prius uses only six cells. Isn't the battery voltage 600 V?

@Hearth They have a battery pack with 28 modules that have 6 cells each. It has about 200 Volts total.
